# Firebase Cloud Function "too many HTTP redirects"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to implement the https callable functions from firebase to my IOS app, but when I call the function from my device I get the following error:

```
    2023-02-18 19:40:38.701646-0600 Spaces[16235:3277636] Task <48F8CCDC-85B7-451F-9D00-FC93D93B7AFC>.<1> finished with error [-1007] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP redirects, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/rejected?continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?state%3D~AJKiYcHgSfXKmjn8R3F7NQNdJB-nW8eUS2Xxxojs23jJxTuoOb6Rt2tr-ooa5vw_yCMFz2P1PZUzwzuI-GSUDkbDWHqF-UQ30JQOejlBnzcpcSAKxl60g4hHYnHsvNyJBRHx2z4JxKohRxTwAGiL9ryos8HHOQp1_0GOfqHncrBjMwXXdHNJoWAXtJ4-bf7K3sfh32yXYxEIkKiTadJMenpzjDp4MCu8LbG5OXVXI1tXqAouERC_B4-JQA2esYzTGw704LdBdksK&dsh=S1057996816:1676770836995843&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&ifkv=AWnogHcLgDBo5gsyBrVbQJMIcoCwk3TXQujaljG27PM2wEBBNE0chcGuSa8bvjDtbyfz1Ii6UodjEw&rhlk=no&rrk=32, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/rejected?continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?state%3D~AJKiYcHgSfXKmjn8R3F7NQNdJB-nW8eUS2Xxxojs23jJxTuoOb6Rt2tr-ooa5vw_yCMFz2P1PZUzwzuI-GSUDkbDWHqF-UQ30JQOejlBnzcpcSAKxl60g4hHYnHsvNyJBRHx2z4JxKohRxTwAGiL9ryos8HHOQp1_0GOfqHncrBjMwXXdHNJoWAXtJ4-bf7K3sfh32yXYxEIkKiTadJMenpzjDp4MCu8LbG5OXVXI1tXqAouERC_B4-JQA2esYzTGw704LdBdksK&dsh=S1057996816:1676770836995843&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&ifkv=AWnogHcLgDBo5gsyBrVbQJMIcoCwk3TXQujaljG27PM2wEBBNE0chcGuSa8bvjDtbyfz1Ii6UodjEw&rhlk=no&rrk=32, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <48F8CCDC-85B7-451F-9D00-FC93D93B7AFC>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <48F8CCDC-85B7-451F-9D00-FC93D93B7AFC>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x28045b2a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1007 "(null)"}}
```

Callable function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
// const fcm = admin.messaging();
const db = admin.firestore();

  exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    // [END addFunctionTrigger]
      // [START readAddData]
      // Numbers passed from the client.
      const firstNumber = data.firstNumber;
      const secondNumber = data.secondNumber;
      // [END readAddData]
    
      // [START addHttpsError]
      // Checking that attributes are present and are numbers.
      if (!Number.isFinite(firstNumber) || !Number.isFinite(secondNumber)) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'two arguments "firstNumber" and "secondNumber" which must both be numbers.');
      }
      // [END addHttpsError]
    
      // [START returnAddData]
      // returning result.
      return {
        firstNumber: firstNumber,
        secondNumber: secondNumber,
        operator: '+',
        operationResult: firstNumber + secondNumber,
      };
      // [END returnAddData]
    });
```

Call from device(IOS, Swift):

```
func callNumbers() {
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
functions.httpsCallable("addNumbers").call(["firstNumber": 10, "secondNumber": 5]) { result, error in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                        let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                        let message = error.localizedDescription
                        let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                    }
                    // ...
                }
                if let data = result?.data {
                   print(data)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I'm trying to implement callable functions so that I can do important tasks from the server and not from the device.

Comment: What is `DispatchQueue.global`? Seems suspect since the function itself looks fine.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu it only runs the function on the background thread, should not affect

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me recently, actually I forgot to export that particular function from my main `index.ts`, so after exporting that function from `index.ts` and then `firebase deploy --only:functions:myFuncName`, it started working!.

`index.ts` (inside `src` folder): (should contain all your functions exports)

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export { saveToCollection } from "./products/saveToCollection";
// could be more

admin.initializeApp();
```

If this was not the case, please do mention below so that others also could get some idea.

Hope this works out for you if it hasn't already!